# Making a boost C++ UdpConnection class thread-safe

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have implemented some connection classes, using Boost ASIO, to replace some low level C code in an application, and everything is working great, except for one problem.

Basically, I have a UdpConnection class that does synchronous read and write, but it uses async methods to handle time-outs as per the boost examples.  The problem is I can't figure out how to make it threadsafe.

I have tried adding strands to the event handlers to make this class threadsafe (code below), but that isn't working.  I suspect it is because of the way timeout is implemented. I have included my code in 4 classes in pastebin.

Single threaded is working fine.  I also have TcpConnection and UnixSocketConnection classes that don't need to be shared amongst multiple threads and they work fine.  However, I can't get multi-threaded UDP code to work.

Am I missing something?

- Connection.h && AsioConnection.h http://pastebin.com/Cbbw37gL
- UdpConnection.h && UdpConnection.cpp http://pastebin.com/VLnHBnPs

EDIT Attaching code as suggested:

**AsioConnection.h**

```
/*
 * AsioConnection.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2011-04-08
 *      Author: cdunphy
 *
 * All classes that want to use the ASIO io_service
 * and deadline timers will want to subclass this.
 */



#ifndef ASIOCONNECTION_H_
#define ASIOCONNECTION_H_

#include "Connection.h"

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace shaw_rsc
{

/*
 * This exception throws if there is a timeout when connecting
 * to a remote socket.
 */
struct SocketTimeoutException : public std::runtime_error
{
    SocketTimeoutException(const std::string& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg)
    { }
}
;

/*
 * This is the root class of every Connection
 * class that wants to make use of boost asio.
 */
class AsioConnection : public Connection
{
public:
    AsioConnection(
        int c_timeout,
        int r_timeout
    ) : Connection(),
            conn_timeout_int(c_timeout),
            read_timeout_int(r_timeout),
            conn_timeout(c_timeout),
            read_timeout(r_timeout),
            io_service(),
            strand(io_service),
            deadline(strand.get_io_service()),
            error()
    {
        reset_deadline();
    }

    const boost::system::error_code& getError() const
    {
        return error;
    }

    int get_read_timeout() const
    {
        return read_timeout_int;
    }
    int get_conn_timeout() const
    {
        return conn_timeout_int;
    }

    /*
        * These are the callback handlers for our asynchronous
        * IO operations.
        */
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                      std::size_t len,
                      boost::system::error_code* out_ec,
                      std::size_t* out_len)
    {
        *out_ec = ec;
        *out_len = len;
    }

    /*
       * These are the callback handlers for our asynchronous
       * IO operations.
       */
    void handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                     std::size_t len,
                     boost::system::error_code* out_ec,
                     std::size_t* out_len)
    {
        *out_ec = ec;
        *out_len = len;
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                     std::size_t len,
                     boost::system::error_code* out_ec,
                     std::size_t* out_len)
    {
        *out_ec = ec;
        *out_len = len;
    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                        std::size_t len,
                        boost::system::error_code* out_ec,
                        std::size_t* out_len)
    {
        *out_ec = ec;
        *out_len = len;
    }

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                        boost::system::error_code* out_ec)
    {
        *out_ec = ec;
    }

protected:
    int conn_timeout_int;
    int read_timeout_int;
    boost::posix_time::seconds conn_timeout;
    boost::posix_time::seconds read_timeout;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::strand strand;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline;
    boost::system::error_code error;

    void reset_deadline()
    {
        // No deadline is required until the first socket operation is started. We
        // set the deadline to positive infinity so that the actor takes no action
        // until a specific deadline is set.
        deadline.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
    }
};

}


#endif /* ASIOCONNECTION_H_ */
```

**Connection.h**

```
/*
 * Connection.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2011-02-25
 *      Author: cdunphy
 */

#ifndef CONNECTION_H_
#define CONNECTION_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace shaw_rsc
{

class Connection;

const std::size_t BUF_SIZE = 128;

/*
 * This is the type of reference we will
 * provide to the clients.
 */
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> ConnPtr;

typedef std::vector<char> DataBuffer;
typedef DataBuffer::iterator DB_Iter;
typedef DataBuffer::const_iterator DB_CIter;

// This is the mode we are using for the connection
enum Mode {
    CLIENT,
    SERVER
};

/*
 * This is a generic class that allows data to be read or
 * written to using a connection.  This is quite abstract
 * and it can be used both for file operations and for
 * network operations.
 */
class Connection
{
public:
    Connection() { }
    virtual ~Connection() { }

    /*
     * This method writes the current contents of the data buffer
     * to the connected resource.  Be sure to set the right data
     * in the buffer by calling the setData method first.
     *
     * The number of bytes written is returned.
     */
    virtual std::size_t write(const DataBuffer& data) = 0;

    /*
     * This method reads data from the connected resource and stores
     * it in our data buffer which we pass in by reference.
     * Please note that it clears whatever data was in the buffer prior to
     * reading.
     *
     * The number of bytes read is returned.
     */
    virtual std::size_t read(DataBuffer& data) = 0;

    virtual const std::string str() const = 0;
};

inline std::vector<unsigned char> convert_data_to_unsigned(const DataBuffer& data)
{
    return std::vector<unsigned char>(data.begin(), data.end());
}

inline std::string dataBufferToStr(const DataBuffer& data)
{
    return std::string(data.begin(), data.end());
}

}

#endif /* CONNECTION_H_ */
```

**UdpConnection.h**

```
/*
 * UdpConnection.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2011-02-25
 *      Author: cdunphy
 */

// Portions Copyright (c) 2003-2011 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
#ifndef DATAGRAMCONNECTION_H_
#define DATAGRAMCONNECTION_H_

#include "AsioConnection.h"

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace shaw_rsc
{

struct UdpException: public std::runtime_error
{
    UdpException(const std::string& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) { }
};

/*
 * This is the concrete class that manages UDP connections.
 */
class UdpConnection: public AsioConnection
{
public:
    /*
     * Use this constructor for clients (connecting to a remote socket).
     */
    UdpConnection(
        const std::string& _host,
        const std::string& _port,
        int r_timeout,
        Mode mode
    ) : AsioConnection(0, r_timeout),
            socket(strand.get_io_service()),
            remote_endpoint(),
            host(_host),
            port(_port)
    {
        check_deadline();
        connect(mode);
    }

    std::size_t write(const DataBuffer& data);
    std::size_t read(DataBuffer& data);
    const std::string str() const;

private:

    void connect(Mode mode);
    void check_deadline();

    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
    std::string host;
    std::string port;
};

}

#endif /* DATAGRAMCONNECTION_H_ */
```

**UdpConnection.cpp**

```
/*
 * UdpConnection.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 2011-02-25
 *      Author: cdunphy
 */

#include "UdpConnection.h"

using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::stringstream;
using std::exception;

using boost::asio::buffer;
using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::system::system_error;
using boost::asio::deadline_timer;
using boost::bind;
using boost::lexical_cast;

namespace shaw_rsc
{

size_t UdpConnection::write(const DataBuffer& data)
{
    size_t bytes_written = 0;

    /*
     * Check to see if the socket is bad before writing
     */
    if (error &&
            error.value() != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted &&
            error.value() != boost::asio::error::timed_out &&
            error != boost::asio::error::try_again)
        throw UdpException(error.message());

    socket.async_send_to(buffer(data), remote_endpoint,
                         strand.wrap(bind(&AsioConnection::handle_send, this, _1, _2,
                                          &error, &bytes_written)));

    do
    {
        strand.get_io_service().run_one();
    }
    while (error == boost::asio::error::would_block
            || error == boost::asio::error::try_again || bytes_written == 0);

    if (error)
    {
        if (error.value() == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted
                || error.value() == boost::asio::error::timed_out)
            throw SocketTimeoutException(error.message());
        else
            throw UdpException(error.message());
    }

    reset_deadline();
    return bytes_written;
}

size_t UdpConnection::read(DataBuffer& data)
{
    /*
    * Check to see if the socket is bad before writing
    */
    if (error &&
            error.value() != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted &&
            error.value() != boost::asio::error::timed_out &&
            error != boost::asio::error::try_again)
        throw UdpException(error.message());

    data.clear();

    /*
     * Reset the deadline timer to expire according
     * to the configured read timeout.
     */
    deadline.expires_from_now(read_timeout);

    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    boost::array<char, BUF_SIZE> buff;

    error = boost::asio::error::would_block;
    socket.async_receive_from(buffer(buff), remote_endpoint,
                              strand.wrap(boost::bind(&AsioConnection::handle_receive, this, _1, _2, &error,
                                                      &bytes_read)));

    do
    {
        strand.get_io_service().run_one();
    }
    while (error == boost::asio::error::would_block ||
            error == boost::asio::error::try_again || bytes_read == 0);

    /*
     * Check for errors after the read.
     */
    if (error)
    {
        if (error.value() == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted
                || error.value() == boost::asio::error::timed_out)
            throw SocketTimeoutException(error.message());
        else
            throw UdpException(error.message());
    }
    else
        data.insert(data.end(), buff.begin(), buff.begin() + bytes_read);

    // Reset the deadline timer so we can leave this socket open as long
    // as we want.
    reset_deadline();
    return bytes_read;
}

void UdpConnection::connect(Mode mode)
{
    socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
    if (mode == SERVER)
    {
        socket.bind(
            udp::endpoint(udp::v4(),
                          lexical_cast<int>(port)), error);
    }
    else if (mode == CLIENT)
    {
        udp::resolver resolver(strand.get_io_service());
        udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, port);
        remote_endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query, error);
    }
}

void UdpConnection::check_deadline()
{
    // Check whether the deadline has passed. We compare the deadline against
    // the current time since a new asynchronous operation may have moved the
    // deadline before this actor had a chance to run.
    if (deadline.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
    {
        // The deadline has passed. The outstanding asynchronous operation needs
        // to be cancelled so that the blocked receive() function will return.
        //
        // Please note that cancel() has portability issues on some versions of
        // Microsoft Windows, and it may be necessary to use close() instead.
        // Consult the documentation for cancel() for further information.
        socket.cancel();

        // There is no longer an active deadline. The expiry is set to positive
        // infinity so that the actor takes no action until a new deadline is set.
        reset_deadline();
    }

    // Put the actor back to sleep.
    deadline.async_wait(strand.wrap(boost::bind(&UdpConnection::check_deadline, this)));
}

/*
 * This member function is good for diagnostic purposes
 */
const string UdpConnection::str() const
{
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr << "Host: " << host << endl;
    sstr << "Port: " << port << endl;
    sstr << "Read timeout: " << read_timeout_int << endl;
    sstr << "Remote Endpoint Address: " << remote_endpoint.address().to_string()
    << endl;
    sstr << "Remote Endpoint Port: " << remote_endpoint.port() << endl;

    try
    {
        sstr << "Socket Remote Endpoint Address: "
        << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << endl;
        sstr << "Socket Remote Endpoint Port: "
        << socket.remote_endpoint().port() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    { }

    try
    {
        sstr << "Socket Local Endpoint Address: "
        << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() << endl;
        sstr << "Socket Local Endpoint Port: " << socket.local_endpoint().port()
        << endl;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    { }

    return sstr.str();
}

}
```

EDIT2:

Here is the test code I am trying to get working:

Server that replies in C++.  All tests are working EXCEPT the threaded Udp test:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestLibRSCAsio

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

#include <rsc_asio/Connection.h>
#include <rsc_asio/TcpConnection.h>
#include <rsc_asio/UdpConnection.h>
#include <rsc_asio/UnixSocketConnection.h>

#include "Util.h"
#include "sha1/Sha1Calc.h"

#include "servers/TestTcpServer.h"

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>


using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::size_t;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::flush;
using std::exception;
using std::time;
using std::stringstream;

using boost::lexical_cast;
using boost::thread;
using boost::mutex;
using boost::unique_lock;

using namespace shaw_rsc;

const size_t TCP_BYTE_SZ = 1000000;
const size_t UDP_BYTE_SZ = 64;

const std::string FILE_SOCKET = "/tmp/rofl";
const std::string SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0";
const std::string SERVER_PORT = "10999";
const std::string EXPECTED_UDP_REQUEST = "GOT_ANSWER?";

const int TIMEOUT = 3;
const int THREAD_TIMEOUT = 10;

DataBuffer write_data(ConnPtr client, Sha1Calc& sha1calc, size_t size, size_t iter)
{
    unique_lock<mutex>(global_mutex);
    cout << "Iter: " << iter << endl;
    DataBuffer data = getRandomData(size);
    sha1calc.calc_client_digest(data);
    size_t bytes_written = client->write(data);
    cout << "Wrote " << bytes_written << " -> " << dataBufferToStr(data) << " to socket: " << endl << client->str() << endl;
    return data;
}

void write_data_threaded(ConnPtr client, Sha1Calc& sha1calc, size_t size, size_t iter)
{
    cout << "Iter: " << iter << endl;
    DataBuffer data = getRandomData(size);
    sha1calc.calc_client_digest(data);
    size_t  bytes_written = client->write(data);
    cout << "Wrote " << bytes_written << " -> " << dataBufferToStr(data) << " to socket: " << endl << client->str() << endl;
}

DataBuffer read_data(ConnPtr server, Sha1Calc& sha1calc, size_t iter)
{
    cout << "Iter: " << iter << endl;
    DataBuffer data;
    size_t bytes_read = server->read(data);
    cout << "Read " << bytes_read << " -> " << dataBufferToStr(data) << " from socket: " << endl << server->str() << endl;
    sha1calc.calc_server_digest(data);
    return data;
}

/*
 * This is a suite of tests to provide unit tests
 * for the RRE.
 */
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestLibRSCAsioSuite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TcpTest)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    cout << endl << "**** TCP Test ****" << endl;
    Sha1Calc sha1calc;
    cout << endl << "Generating " << TCP_BYTE_SZ << " bytes of data to serve up." << endl;
    DataBuffer dataToServe = getRandomData(TCP_BYTE_SZ);
    sha1calc.calc_server_digest(dataToServe);
    cout << "SHA1 hash of server data: " <<
    sha1_to_str(sha1calc.get_server_digest()) << endl;
    SrvPtr server(new TestTcpServer(std::atoi(SERVER_PORT.c_str()), dataToServe, io_service));
    server->start();

    try
    {
        // Fire up a basic TCP client for testing
        cout << "Firing up TCP client on port: " << SERVER_PORT << endl;
        DataBuffer clientData;
        ConnPtr client(new TcpConnection(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT, io_service));
        size_t bytesRead = client->read(clientData);

        BOOST_REQUIRE( bytesRead == TCP_BYTE_SZ );
        BOOST_REQUIRE( clientData.size() == TCP_BYTE_SZ );
        sha1calc.calc_client_digest(clientData);
        BOOST_REQUIRE( sha1calc.compare() );// SHA-1 hashes better matctype filter texth

    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException& e)
    {
        cerr << "Socket timeout: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("Socket Timeout");
    }
    catch (const TcpException& e)
    {
        cerr << "TCP Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("TCP Exception");
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "Other Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("Unknown Exception");
    }

}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(UdpTest)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::stringstream error;
    try
    {
        cout << endl << "**** UDP Test ****" << endl;

        ConnPtr client(new UdpConnection(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, TIMEOUT, CLIENT, io_service));
        ConnPtr server(new UdpConnection(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, TIMEOUT, SERVER, io_service));

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
            Sha1Calc sha1calc;

            // Write the data to the client
            DataBuffer clientData = write_data(client, sha1calc, UDP_BYTE_SZ, i);

            // Read the data from the server
            DataBuffer serverData = read_data(server, sha1calc, i);

            // Make sure the client data matches the server data
            BOOST_REQUIRE( sha1calc.compare() );

            cout << endl; // new-line
        }
    }
    catch (const SocketTimeoutException& e)
    {
        error << "Socket timeout: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
    catch (const UdpException& e)
    {
        error << "UDP Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        error << "Other Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(UdpThreadTest)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::stringstream error;
    try
    {
        cout << endl << "**** UDP Multi-thread Test ****" << endl;
        ConnPtr server(new UdpConnection(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, THREAD_TIMEOUT, SERVER, io_service));
        Sha1Calc sha1calc;

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
            // Read the data from the server, make sure it matches
            // the expected request?
            DataBuffer serverData = read_data(server, sha1calc, i);
            BOOST_REQUIRE(dataBufferToStr(serverData) == EXPECTED_UDP_REQUEST);

            // Repply on the remote socket
            thread t1(bind(&write_data_threaded, server, sha1calc, UDP_BYTE_SZ, i));
            cout << endl; // new-line


        }
    }
    catch (const SocketTimeoutException& e)
    {
        error << "Socket timeout: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
    catch (const UdpException& e)
    {
        error << "UDP Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        error << "Other Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL(error.str());
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(UnixSocketTest)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    try
    {
        cout << endl << "**** UNIX Socket Test ****" << endl;

        std::remove(FILE_SOCKET.c_str());
        ConnPtr server(new UnixSocketConnection(FILE_SOCKET, TIMEOUT, SERVER, io_service));
        ConnPtr client(new UnixSocketConnection(FILE_SOCKET, TIMEOUT, CLIENT, io_service));

        Sha1Calc sha1calc;

        DataBuffer clientData = write_data(client, sha1calc, UDP_BYTE_SZ, 0);
        cout << "Wrote the data to the Unix Socket client:" << dataBufferToStr(clientData) << endl;

        DataBuffer serverData = read_data(server, sha1calc, 0);
        cout << "Read from UDP Server: " << dataBufferToStr(serverData) << endl;

        BOOST_REQUIRE( sha1calc.compare() );
        cout << sha1_to_str(sha1calc.get_server_digest()) << endl;

    }
    catch (const SocketTimeoutException& e)
    {
        cerr << "Socket timeout: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("Socket Timeout");
    }
    catch (const UnixSocketException& e)
    {
        cerr << "UNIX Socket Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("UNIXSocket Exception");
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "Other Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        BOOST_FAIL("Unknown Exception");
    }

    std::remove(FILE_SOCKET.c_str());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

    }
```

Client written in Java:

```
package com.shaw.udp.sender;

import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(0);
        SocketAddress client = new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_HOST, 10999);
        DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();

        // This is the local socket
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        socket.bind(address);

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
            // Send the data to the remote server
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("GOT_ANSWER?".getBytes());
            channel.send(buffer, client);
            System.out.println("Iter: " + i + " => Sent request: "
                    + new String(buffer.array()));

            // Listen for reply from the server
            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
            channel.receive(buffer);
            System.out.println("Iter: " + i + " => Got reply: "
                    + new String(buffer.array()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code in the question itself, not as links to paste bin.com which may rot over time.

Comment: @Sam: Done on Nebulaeus' behalf..

Comment: I have done this as per the suggestion, thanks

Comment: @Nebulaeus why are you using an `io_service` per `AsioConnection` object? The typical methodology for an asynchronous program is a single `io_service` with one or more threads invoking `io_service::run()`.

Comment: can you post a complete example demonstrating the problem? I see no usage of threads in the code you have posted.

Comment: I have tried to share io_service and that did not work.  I'll post the test client code.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is not concurrent reads or concurrent writes, but my application has to read on one thread, and reply on another.  My test is trying to replicate that behaviour from the application.

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755726/reusing-a-port-number-in-a-udp