# UDP hole punching on 1 port?

Tags: udp, hole-punching

I want to use UDP to send PUSH notifications for users of our system , but i wonder if it will work ?

Assuming i have one server which have port let's say UDP:8888 open and waiting for connections . My questions are :

- Is it possible for many users to connect to it ? (Like the HTTP 90 service ?)
- If yes , after the clients connection , i will grab his UDP port number and IP address > can i establish a new connection from the server to the clients UDP port and send him some data ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you say Server at Port UDP:8888 it will be able to receive connection from multiple client
2. Use SO_REUSEADDR  to resuse same UDP port. [Reusing a port number in a UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755726/reusing-a-port-number-in-a-udp)